# How to set and access per request variable in Flask python

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I want to read request argument and set it in some variable so that I should be able to access it anywhere down the line.I tried to use g and call context but it is giving me errors like

> 'Working outside of application context.'

Is it possible to achieve it using Flask?
Is there alternative solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Use `app_context`. It keeps track of the application-level data during a request, CLI command, or other activity.

Read [link](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/appcontext/) for more infrmation

Example:

```
from app import app

with app.app_context():
     print("Set or Access request variable")
```

Comment: The example given in link is not appropriate for me.If possible post sample example somewhere and share the link

Answer (score 1):

Storing values globally not the best solution. And you can't store value in flask.g and expect to be available in the next request, well it's not. So I advise you to look into database or session to store value and access anywhere.

```
from flask import Flask, g

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def index():
    if "count" not in g:
        g.count = 0

    g.count += 1
    print(g.count)
    return "This is index"
```

Comment: I want value in same request not in next request

Comment: I've updated my answer. If that not works can you update your question with relevant code.

Comment: This works in flask api but not everywhere in the code.I am using contextvars to achieve my purpose